# Indent code for SharePoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Are there any functions in SharePoint designer 2007 that can arrange my coding in correct indent. I tried the right click and select **Reformat HTML** but it only format my HTML code only. All the CSS and Javascript and other scripts are in wrong indent / format.

I am also open for any standalone solution (and preferable portable ones) that can help me arrange my coding inside SharePoint Designer 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Designer 2007 is pretty horrible when it comes to formatting and indentation. It always insists on moving things around the way it thinks best, which I find is rarely aligned with basic common sense.

You should extract your CSS and Javascript and edit them in another editor. Visual Studio does a much better job (Ctrl-K,D), if you can have it. If not there are code formatting plugins for NotePad++ or TextPad.

Extracting your code will also ease reuse and caching.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is very little effort from Microsoft's side when it comes to SharePoint Designer add-ins. You can try the following link:

[TechNet: how to develop custom add-in for sharepoint designer 2010](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010customization/thread/be3c20bf-f842-46ae-8cf1-a2dd81a6c4dc)